# onevent on f:ajax causes model to not getting updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf-2, tinymce

I've added TinyMCE on a website (JSF-2, Tomcat 7, Mojarra 2.1.6). When a user clicks on a 'refresh' button the html text inside the editor is parsed and printed somewhere else on the page.

I have to turn off TinyMCE before the Ajax request (otherwise I will end up with two editors). This is also recommended in the TinyMCE documentation.

So I added an f:ajax event to the button:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg['rt.refresh']}" action="#{updateTextAction.execute}" onclick="cleanupRte();">
<f:ajax event="action" execute="@this" render="@all" onevent="disposeTinyMce" />
</h:commandButton>
```

the javascript functions are called properly:

```
function cleanupRte() {
  tinyMCE.triggerSave();

  return true;
}
```

and the onevent method:

```
function disposeTinyMce(e) {

    if(e.status == 'begin') {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();

        var elem = document.getElementById("mainForm:rteExtAdr:input");
        alert(elem.value);

        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'mainForm:rteExtAdr:input');
    }
    if(e.status == 'complete') {
    }
    if(e.status == 'success') { 
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'mainForm:rteExtAdr:input');
    }

    return true;
}
```

which disables the editor and adds it back to the page. This is working fine.

The problem is the model is not updated with the value from the textfield although the alert shows the correct value. The request also contains the 'old' value from the textfield.

Is there something that would prevent the ajax call to see the current form values?
or does it read the values before it executes the onevent function?

If I remove the f:ajax tag completely the model is updated but then I have the issues with the TinyMce editor getting duplicated after the response.

the init call:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_selector : "sesamWysiwyg", 
    language : "de",
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    inline_styles : false,
    forced_root_block : '', // Needed for 3.x
    plugins : "autolink,lists,style,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,searchreplace,print,paste,directionality,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,wordcount,advlist",

    formats : {
            underline : {inline : 'u', exact : true},
            strikethrough : {inline : 'del', exact : true}
    },

    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,underline,strikethrough,|,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,search,replace,|,undo,redo,|,code,removeformat,|,charmap",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",

        content_css : "css/content.css",

    });
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be great!

thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, usually `triggerSave()` is the way to go here. I do not know what went wrong here. can you show use the initial tinymce init call (the configuration)?

Comment: well I'm almost sure it is more of a JSF issue. The alert() shows the correct value after the triggerSave(). I'll add the init call above.

Comment: The tinymce side is not the problem here. Even though the OP checked the ajax request content and confirmed that the submited content was ok (updated), JSF did not update the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not caused by the `onevent` handler function. This is caused by the `execute="@this"` attribute. The `@this` basically means that only the *current* component will be executed/processed. If you want to process the entire form, including all the containing input elements, you need to use `execute="@form"` instead.

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg['rt.refresh']}" action="#{updateTextAction.execute}" onclick="cleanupRte();">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@all" onevent="disposeTinyMce" />
</h:commandButton>
```

This way the model will be updated with the values of all processed input elements.

Or if you want to process certain inputs only, you need to use for example `execute="input"` where `input` is the ID of the input component. It can take a space separated string of (relative) client IDs.

---

As to reinventing the wheel, just look at component libraries. [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) for example has [a `<p:editor>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf). It's then a matter of only

```
<p:editor value="#{bean.text}" />
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" />
```

without any hassle with custom scripts.

Comment: That saved my day. I don't know how many times I read over the @this without thinking...

We currently use ICEfaces 3.0.0 but had to tweak the editor quite a bit anyway, therefore we decided to go the hard way.

Thanks a lot!